# Conditional class in HtmlBars

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

In regular handlebars I was able to do:

```
<div {{bind-attr class="model.isNew:new:old"}}>
```

How can I do this in Htmlbars?  I tried this but it didn't work.

```
<div class="{{model.isNew:new:old}}">
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This was mentioned in [the 1.10 release/1.11 beta blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_bound-attribute-syntax):

```
<div class="{{if model.isNew 'new' 'old'}}">
```

You can also still use the `{{bind-attr}}` helper, although I think it might be deprecated.

Comment: Any idea where this is documented?

Comment: Unfortunately I've only seen it in that blog post and the PR. I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: This is an unfortunate design decision. I made frequent use of the `{{bind-attr class="isFoo"}}` style, which automatically generated the `is-foo` class. Now I have to write `class="{{if isFoo 'is-foo'}}"`. A step backward. In the syntax `class="{{isFoo}}"`, if `isFoo` is boolean, it should mimic the old behavior by generating `class="is-foo"` instead of the meaningless `class="true"`.

Comment: Remember though, you can now use _any_ Handlebars expression there. So you could easily write a helper that would allow you to do this: `{{toggle-class isFoo}}`. You can even use subexpressions. `bind-attr` was cool when it's all we had, but the sky is the limit now!

Comment: Anyone looking for the 1.13 documentation for this feature, it is here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/binding-element-class-names/

Comment: As of today, you don't need the double-quotes around the mustaches, it would look like : `class={{if shouldDisplayFooter 'with-footer'}}`

Comment: thank you! I used `#if` with following error, so simple but it didn't reach me